# ksysguard in recent KDE task bar

Tags: kde

In an ancient KDE installation I had a sysguard applet in the taskbar. This was quite useful since I could see immedeately when the system was running out of memory or something similar. It looked like this: https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/2288.html

Is this possible with current KDE? I cannot figure out how to do it. I get some text info but this takes too much space in the task bar.